# Android onChangeListener

Tags: android, text, listener

Could somebody help me to create my own Listener.
I have an Activity where a String is changing and in an Activity's fragment I have to set a TextView's text for this String.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using Activity and Activity fragment?
just use fragment and make an interface
    public interface ddd
    {
      void MyTestInterface(String str);
    }
make your activityFragment implement it and than just pass your activity (this) to the other fragment how handle the string changes.
like: MyTestInterface.stringCallback("str")